# In what format should we post hand discussion questions?

Tags: discussion, hand-history-questions

I just posted a [question for a hand discussion](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/2736/hand-discussion-qjc-vs-a8o-on-a84-t-k). But I'm not sure if this is the right format.

What are the main points of a question about a played hand?

This is my opinion best practise should look like:

1. Show the hand/move what you are talking about.
2. Say why you did what you did and what you would have done if villian did something else.
3. Ask your question about this hand.

In my case I was just curious if I did everything right or if it was just luck and I am a fish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a general perspective, the MIT feedback model is something I've found useful for almost everything, and definitely poker hand histories.

[image]

If you're looking for a general idea of what to include regarding your personal thought process at the time, then I find this an excellent guide.

For hand histories, there are many good examples of using the markup code of the site to format raw HH's into a readable, useful format. Just remember, it's more important to accurately represent what **you** were thinking at the time, as changing those decisions will be the ultimate influence on your future success.

Comment: Maybe we can re-create this sheet with a poker example. So that we can link in questions of format to this page and your answer.